# Get fullUrl in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i have multiple bootstrap tabs where each one do different action from others tabs for exmaple

`app-url/users#creat-admin-users-tab` `app-url/users#creat-regular-users-tab`

**Is there any way in Laravel to get full url including the #tab-name**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: noway i need the url not all my server info

Comment: Now where do you want to get it? Like do you want to use it in blade or somewhere in your jquery or so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the following

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] => Host name from the current request.`

`$_SERVER['HTTP'] =>  Set to a non-empty value if the protocol is HTTP`

`$_SERVER['HTTPS'] =>  Set to a non-empty value if the protocol is HTTPS`

`$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] => Server port. Default is: 80`

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] =>  The URI to access this page;`

Comment: WARNING: bad idea. Anything starting with 'HTTP_' is sent by the client, do not rely on it.

Answer (score 82):

Laravel has functionality to return you the current url. It is all specified in this page: http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Http/Request.html

What you are looking for is `Request::fullUrl()`.

Let's say I'm on *http://laravel.dev/test?test=1*, here are the methods and the results:

```
Request::fullUrl()
// Returns: http://laravel.dev/test?test=1
Request::url()
// Returns: http://laravel.dev/test
Request::path()
// Returns: test
Request::root()
// Returns: http://laravel.dev
```

Comment: I used it  before it's return all url but without `#tab-name`

Comment: The server does not know what content after *#*, it's only for the user. You have to append it yourself.

Comment: the all tabs including in one route using `Route::match` so i want to check   what the current tab to do the proper action 
i think the best  way in this case  is `$request->isMethod('')`
but i don't know what i do if there multiple post or put method .

Comment: You can't check `#` values in the backend. You can do what with [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery).

Comment: @JustUser if you have separate `<form>` on each tab, you can put a kind of tab identifier into a hidden field of this form. If it's one large form, spread on all your tabs, you could still use the hidden field, but you'll need to update its value (current tab ID) using JavaScript.

Comment: @Andrius let's say http://whitelabel_eb.test/users/login?next=projects/3/interest?id=1&source=eoi this is my URL I want to go to next URL but all I am getting is projects/3/interest?id=1 after that it's not capturing anything.

Comment: For me, `url()->full()` was helpful, in addition to `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::fullUrl()`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-url

Answer (score 5):

It's true - the only way to get the "#" for now is to use js e.g. like this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var tabName1 = '#creat-admin-users-tab';
var tabName2 = '#creat-regular-users-tab';
if (hash.indexOf(tabName1) !== -1) console.log("It's creat-admin-users-tab");
else if (hash.indexOf(tabName2) !== -1) console.log("It's creat-regular-users-tab");
```

And this can help you for the other parts of the url (add it in your route file):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/app-url/users', function (Request $request) {
    $fullUrl = $request->fullUrl();
    var_dump($fullUrl);
});
```