# how to get full url with # in laravel

Tags: laravel, url

I am using laravel 5 and I am trying to get my full url which is 
/faq#manual 
However I can only get /faq 
when I call the function 
Request::url() or Request::fullUrl()
is there any way I can get the full url 
with #manual?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get fullUrl in laravel 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33687496/get-fullurl-in-laravel-5-1)

Comment: Request::fullUrl() will not return with a url fragment. If you want the fragment you will need to do that client side.

Comment: how can I get the full url with the # on the client side? I want to show it in my blade. can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to get **the fragment** from a URL with **Standard HTTP**. So using variables like $_SERVER or $_GET can't help you. Actually, the server never knows about this value because the browser **won't even send** a request with a fragment part.

If you want to have the fragment value in the server side, you should get the value by **javascript** first then **pass** it as a URL parameter and get it by **$_GET** in your server side.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in http or php however you can use javascript to get the full url including the hash.

```
var url = document.URL;
```

or

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeap thank you very much for your answer! It helped!!